# Unexpected token (6:6)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to generate a business network archive but I am getting the following error while running `composer archive create -t dir -n .`

```
Creating Business Network Archive
Looking for package.json of Business Network Definition

SyntaxError: Failed to parse /Users/xxxx@xxxx.com/fabric-tools/tutorial-network/lib/logic.js: Unexpected token (6:6)

Command failed
```

Unexpected token (6:6)?
the content of the logic.js are below:

```
cat lib/logic.js
/**
* Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
* @param {org.acme.mynetwork.Trade} trade - the trade to be processed
* @transaction
*/
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
    trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
    let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.mynetwork.Commodity');
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
}
```

Comment: does it support async-await?

Comment: Which version of `composer` you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `composer v0.16.x`, `async` and `ES6` keywords are not supported. There is an issue with it. You can check [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3382). If you want to use these keywords you need to upgrade `composer` to `v0.17.4` or higher.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get answer for this on the Hyperledger community support and it is also exactly what @mohammadjh mentioned here. The version of composer that I initially had was outdated and getting the latest one resolved the issue. Here is how you get the latest version:
npm install -g composer-cli