# Hyperledger composer fails to create .bna file. Unexpected token.

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to generate a .bna file following this -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html tutorial.
But when I'm running the command 'composer archive create -t dir -n .' Instead of generating a new .bna file I get the following error:
code in logic.js :

```
/**
 * Track the trade of a commodity from one trader to another
 * @param {org.example.biznet.Trade} trade - the trade to be processed
 * @transaction
 */
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
    trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
    let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.example.biznet.Commodity');
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
}
console.log("Node?");
```

```
SyntaxError: Failed to parse /Users/marcello/tutorial-network/lib/logic.js: Unexpected token (6:6)
```

It looks like composer doesn't recognise the async syntax.
When I run this code using node everything is ok.

It's my full repo of the project: 
https://github.com/Jonbi2/marcellos-hyperledger-composer-repo
I use this dependencies:
node : v8.11.3
npm : 5.6.0
composer : v0.16.6
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have Composer v0.16 installed, but you are following a tutorial for v0.19.x.  There are many important changes between those versions, including support for **async** functions in v0.19.x

[This Q/A earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298238/facing-issue-with-hyperledger-playground-tutorial) has a very similar problem with steps to fix.